# Java, generics mismatch

Tags: java

Im new to JAVA programming, but used to programmed in Delphi/Pascal so I know about types.

A domain class:

```
public class Domain extends BaseObject {
```

the BaseObject is just an abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseObject {
```

There is a function which has to accept a domain:

```
final Class<BaseObject> objectType = new Domain("1"); // here is an error
something.load2(objectType);
```

The load2 is

```
public <T extends BaseObject> T load2 (Class<T> objectType, Object... parameters) {
```

The problem is with the line in comment:

Type mismatch: cannot convert from Domain to Class

I thought the `load2()` may accept anything which extends `BaseObject`, so `Domain` too. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You get the class of an instance like this:

```
 Domain d = new Domain("1");
 Class<? extends Domain> objectType = d.getClass();
```

Or, if you know the type already at compile-time (no need to look up from an instance):

```
 Class<Domain> objectType = Domain.class;
```

Note, however, that this is `Class<Domain>`, not `Class<BaseObject>`, and the two types are not assignment-compatible.

The best you can do (and it looks like this is what you want is)

```
Class<? extends BaseObject> objectType = Domain.class;
// or
Class<? extends BaseObject> objectType = domain.getClass();
```

Answer (score 2):

The error has nothing to do with `load2` but rather with your object creation:

```
final Class<BaseObject> objectType;
```

means, that `objectType` holds class information about a class of type `BaseObject` and you initialize it with an object of `Domain`. Try initializing it with an object of `Class<Domain>` similar to

```
final Class<BaseObject> objectType = BaseObject.class;
```

or

```
final Class<? extends BaseObject> objectType = Domain.class;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your miss-understanding is in what is `class` and what is `Class` (please pay attention on the case of letter "c")

Keyword `class` is used to define user defined types or classes. Class `Class` is a class that represents other class` metadata.

In your case re-write your wrong statement as following:

```
final BaseObject objectType = new Domain("1"); // now this should not cause error
something.load2(objectType);
```

If however you will want to discover your `Domain` class itself, e.g. check dynamically whether it implements method `foo()` or has field `bar` you will use `Class` and reflection API.

Comment: yea, thanks, but now it causes error at the load2: The method load2(Class<T>, Object...) in the type IObjectRepository is not applicable for the arguments (TSMObject, String)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
final Class<BaseObject> objectType = new Domain("1"); // here is an error
```

try

```
final Class<? extends BaseObject> objectType = new Domain("1").getClass();
```

or

```
final BaseObject objectType = new Domain("1");
```

But in the second case you'll have to change the load2 method.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is  that `objectType`  is of type `Class<BaseObject>` and not `Class<Domain>`.

This is the issue.

You can do the following:

```
Class<? extends BaseObject> objectType = Domain.class;
```

to come out of the problems you have.